# Porting a Play Project to Lagom

Tags: playframework, lagom

I'm currently investigating whether porting a large monolithic Play project into several Lagom projects is worth the effort.

All internal calls (functions with request/response classes) to databases need to be separated away, so that I can start to use those database calls in another separated project.
Developing with Play style I would start a new project and bind those functions to routes and Controller functions.
But afterwards I had to implement those new API calls twice; back in the monolith and in the new project.

There are about ~150 functions that need to be refactored, so has anybody a clue whether Lagom is the best solution to separate calls away to reuse them in several projects so that I don't have to implement the API calls twice?

Does someone have experience with refactoring a Play project to Lagom? Anything that I should be aware of?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: This doesn't really seem on-topic for StackOverflow as it's posed.

Comment: @erip where should I post it then, any constructive ideas?

Comment: You could try the Lagom gitter, or https://discuss.lightbend.com/c/lagom.

Comment: @erip thank you, will raise this questions there then.